# AngularJS & Rails - Seperated apps/deployments or one app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, angularjs

Most of the resources/example about rails and angular on the internet just put them together. AngularJS goes inside of rails under app/assets. This feels reeeaaaly dirty to me. Is it a good idea? What if we decide at some time we won't be using rails and we move to, I don't know, sinatra? How hard would it be to port?

What would be pros/cons of everthing in a single rails app and what would be pros/cons for two seperated apps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when placing Angular (or any other client-side MV* framework) inside your Rails app, you are pretty much keeping the separation of concerns intact. That is, you have a Rails API serving JSON (or similar) data, and a separate Javascript framework using that data to render appropriate views. If you ever wanted to use a different server-side API, you can do so, and still utilize your entire Javascript directory as is.

Placing the client side framework in Rails is simply a matter of convenience. It comes with an organized directory structure and the ability to serve your HTML, which is essentially all you're using it for when it comes to your views. But again, these views aren't really tied to Rails, as they're just HTML and Javascript, so you can easily move them to a different platform when necessary.